# SQL Command which acts on table joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner in sql. I am faced with the following problem.

Table1

```
c1,c2
1,11
2,22
```

Table2

```
c2,c3
22,221
22,231
```

I have to join tables on c2 but eliminate a row of c1 from the join result if and only if data for c2 exists in table 2, so I am taking the following approach

Step 1:-

```
select t1.c1,
       t1.c2,
       t2.c3 as c3 
into #temp 
from Table1 t1 
     left join Table t2 
         on t1.c2 = t2.c2
```

Step 2:-

```
delete from #temp where c3 is null
```

This approach is actually deleting the result of `1,11,null` as well because it got created as a part of left join. I only wanted the data of `2,22,null` to get deleted.

Is there a command available which checks this condition ?

Thanks!

Comment: Given your data and query, `2,22,null` should not be created.

Comment: For the sake of argument let's assume that `{2,22,null}` would be created by another Insert Statement. Why would you want to delete 2 and not 1

Comment: Let me verify the results as the data is not in front of me. Let me close the question and put the question again with results.

Comment: @100pipers Just edit the original. Don't close/repost. People here _hate_ that.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question what criteria you're using. Regardless, temp tables and delete statements are not the answer here. A simple WHERE clause should cover it:

```
select t1.c1,
       t1.c2,
       t2.c3 as c3 
from Table1 t1 
left join Table t2 on t1.c2 = t2.c2
where t1.c2 <> 22
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am closing the question and re-post it with results.

Comment: @100pipers Don't close/repost!  That's now how Stack Overflow works. Instead, **edit** your original post.